# Expectation-Maximisation - Appropriate for very small n? Separate analysis required for different groups?

Tags: expectation-maximization

1) I am interested in applying EM to a small sample including three groups each with n= 24. It is a matched pairs design. Is anyone aware of any studies that show the efficacy of EM with samples under n=50?

2) Do you need to run the EM imputation separately for the different groups?

3) I have some variables that are not applicable across all three groups and thus data is intentionally missing. Will this be in issue if I just delete these values after the fact?

Thanks!

Study description:
The study looks at facial emotion recognition abilities, moderating effects of movement cues and emotion intensity. I also explore the link between emotion recognition ability and social skills. I have three groups which I would like to comapare: People with intellectual disability, mental age matched controls and chronologically age matched controls.

I am using the data to compute Pearson's correlations, linear regression and repeated measures ANOVA. The ANOVA is being used to accommodate for the matched pairs design.

Comment: But you want to use EM for what kind of models and what kind of data? (2) and (3) are unanswerable unless you tell us more about it.

Comment: Thanks for your response Tim

I have included a summary of the study as part of my original post.
 
(2) I only have full scale and subscale scores, but I am informed that there was no missing item level data. Missing data is in the form of missing full scale and subscale scores. I do not know whether the relationship between variables differs as a function of group. For this reason, I thought that I might need to run EM separately for each groups data?

(3) Some measures of social skills are shared across the 3 groups while others are used exclusively by one group.

Comment: EM stands for [*Expectation*-Maximisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm). I will fix your title.